# Transferring data from the third activity to the first

Tags: java, android

From the first activity I would like to go to the second, then from the second to the third. In the third activity I would like to enter the name in EditText, then after pressing the button, go to the first activity and at the same time send the information entered in the third activity.

Unfortunately, after pressing the button in the third activity, instead of returning to the first activity, I return to the second activity. Was the first activity killed? What could I do to ensure that the information is correct for the first activity? This is my code:

First:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textViewInformation;
    Button button_GoToSecond;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewInformation = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button_GoToSecond = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button_GoToSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent i) {

        if((requestCode == 1) &&(resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {

            String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
            textViewInformation.setText(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Second:

```
public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button_GoToThird;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        button_GoToThird = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button_GoToThird.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Second.this, Third.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Third:

```
public class Third extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText_Data;
    Button button_SendData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        editText_Data = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button_SendData = findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button_SendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    public void finish() {

        String name;
        name = editText_Data.getText().toString();

        Intent i = new Intent(Third.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("name", name);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        super.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it goes to the second activity is because of this:

```
 button_SendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            finish();
        }
    });

 public void finish() {

    String name;
    name = editText_Data.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(Third.this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("name", name);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    super.finish(); //This kills the current activity.
}
```

You should do:

```
public void finish() {

        String name;
        name = editText_Data.getText().toString();

        Intent i = new Intent(Third.this, MainActivity.class);
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putString("name", name);

        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_OK, bundle); 
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent i) {

    if((requestCode == 1) &&(resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
        String name = bundle.getString("name");
        textViewInformation.setText(name);
    }
}
```

When you call `finish`, it just kills the current activity. If you want to go back to the first activity, just start a new activity for the first activity and pass the data in a `Bundle`.

If you want to have more of a stack concept, you can use `Fragments`.

Comment: I followed your instructions, the difference is that I'm going back to the first activity, so it's definitely better. But ... unfortunately, no information is displayed in TextView, as if nothing has been sent to the first activity.

Comment: Have debugged the app? I would check to make sure you are getting into `onActivityResult()`. If you are, check your response code to make sure the expected data is working correctly in your conditional statement.

Comment: @UnknownBoy I updated my answer, it was incomplete. I'm sorry.

Comment: Where should I receive data? Can it still be an onActivityResult method? Because I did everything according to your recommendations, but I still have the impression that this method is not called. Unless I am trying to receive this data in an inappropriate way. Could you give me a hint as to what should I do when I receive data? Because I tried in all ways and nothing ...

Comment: You would still receive it in the `onActivityResult` method. I updated my answer again. I added the `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but still the method is not called for unknown reasons. However, when I try to receive data in the onCreate method, the receipt of data results in success. Is it by accident the onActivityResult method is not called only when the finish () method is used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197067/discussion-between-blackhatsamurai-and-unknownboy).

Answer (score 1):

just remove finish(); thats it